# convert each pdf page to jpg

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

i wanna convert each page of a pdf to a jpg file. Converting a single page works:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/convert -density 288 -resize 50% -quality 85 -    colorspace CMYK dv.pdf[8] -colorspace RGB test.jpg');
```

Converting all pages does not work:

```
    exec('/usr/local/bin/convert -density 288 -resize 50% -quality 85 -    colorspace CMYK dv.pdf -colorspace RGB test.jpg');
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: which "convert" is that?

Comment: sorry, i pasted the second "convert" by mistake. Code fixed. Problem still exists...

Comment: @peter this isn't really a php question since the php code just executing the `convert` command line program and you question is about `convert`, not php. Try running your command in a terminal and post the any errors you receive when doing that.

Comment: thx, the error is: convert: Postscript delegate failed `/home/httpd/docs/test/magazine/best/dv.pdf': No such file or directory @ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/630.
convert: missing an image filename `/home/httpd/docs/die8test2/magazine/best/ateste.jpg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2819.

Comment: but the file is there - by adding a page number dv.pdf[8] converting a single page works

Answer (score 0):

you could use imagick to do this. More information can be found here at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

```
 <?php 
    $imagick = new Imagick(); 
    $imagick->readImage('myfile.pdf'); 
    $imagick->writeImages('converted.jpg', false); 
    ?>
```

Comment: thx, that works great - but the color of images is not the same as in pdf. The pdf is CMYK. How can i get correct colors using your example?

Comment: if color becomes inverted, read the user contributed notes at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php which shows different workarounds.

Comment: no changes... according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830478/php-imagick-rgb-to-cmyk-inverts -  php imagick is not doing it, i need to do it with imagick command line as in my original post above. So the problem still exists..

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve the problem, but i found an alternative solution - im executing Ghostscript without using Imagick:

```
exec(
    "'gs' '-dNOPAUSE' '-sDEVICE=jpeg' '-dUseCIEColor' '-dTextAlphaBits=4' 
    '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4' '-o$exportPath' '-r$res' '-dJPEGQ=$quality' '$input'",
     $output
);
```